# Oracle SQL Update with rowover partition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Why do I get the error that `B1.EMPLOYEE_ID` is invalid identifier for the SQL Below:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 A1 
  SET A1.ADDL_SEQ = ( SELECT SEQ 
                        FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                                        ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID, ERNCD) SEQ
                                FROM TABLE_1) B1 
                       WHERE B1.EMPLOYEE_ID=A1.EMPLOYEE_ID );
```

Comment: You did not `select` employee_id in the sub-query aliased as `B1`

Comment: Thank you. now I am getting the error "single-row subquery returns more than one row". What I am trying to achieve is increment the value of sequence number IF EMPOYEE_ID,ERNCD is same

Answer (score 2):

You can write your update statement also like this:

```
UPDATE 
   (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, ADDL_SEQ, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID, ERNCD) AS SEQ
   FROM TABLE_1)
SET ADDL_SEQ = SEQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add EMPLOYEE_ID to your B1 inner query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 A1 
  SET A1.ADDL_SEQ = ( SELECT SEQ 
                        FROM (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                                        ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID, ERNCD) SEQ
                                FROM TABLE_1) B1 
                       WHERE B1.EMPLOYEE_ID=A1.EMPLOYEE_ID );
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a case statement, like this

```
 UPDATE TABLE_1 A1 
      SET A1.ADDL_SEQ = ( SELECT  
                            (CASE WHEN  employee_id = ERNCD THEN seq ELSE NULL END) AS SEQ
                            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                                            ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID, ERNCD) SEQ
                                    FROM TABLE_1) B1 
                           WHERE B1.EMPLOYEE_ID=A1.EMPLOYEE_ID );
```

I don't think you need the WHERE condition but Its kind of hard to visualize the data